# How to use SASS with Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, sass

I want to add SASS to my project, I'm using Symfony 4.2.1 / Ubuntu 16.04

Here is the commands I've use:

```
composer require encore
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
yarn install
```

So I have a webpack.config.js file the Documentation say:

```
// webpack.config.js
// ...

Encore
    // ...

    // enable just the one you want

    // processes files ending in .scss or .sass
    .enableSassLoader()

    // processes files ending in .less
    .enableLessLoader()

    // processes files ending in .styl
    .enableStylusLoader()
;
```

There is a Encore object.

In another tutorial I see:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

It totally different type file the documentation say (the first code)

And my file look as:

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
require('../css/app.css');

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
// const $ = require('jquery');

console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
```

It is another different type of file again!

What must I do now ? (I've made nothing after 'yarn install')

Answer (score 0):

Your first `webpack.config` file has been setup to use Encore, a Symfony component that wraps webpack to provide an easy to use API.

The second `webpack.config` file is not using Encore, it is a traditional webpack setup.

Since you are using the latest version of Symfony you probably want to use the first, which provides a much easier to understand API.

You can read more about Encore in the symfony docs here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/css-preprocessors.html

Comment: The first is not mine, it is from documentation and it is the file I want to use !! But my file (and I've got only one) it's the second

Comment: This link will provide instructions to get encore setup:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html#creating-the-webpack-config-js-file